# Opposit to @JavascriptInterface in Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I know how to call `Java` method in `JavaScrip`t code. It is done by `@JavascriptInterface` annotation. But what if I want to determine by `Android` which method **from** `JS` should be called? I'm calling an Android `Dialog` in JS using the mentioned annotation where I've got the switch statement which should determine which function should be called in JS. I used a flag which is not working because Dialogs are not synchronized so the method `showDialog()` is done before even Dialog starts. Is there any way to reach the Android-JS communication on the opposite side?

```
@JavascriptInterface
public int showDialog(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this.activity)
            .setTitle("Share iamge as...")
            .setItems(new CharSequence[]{"Image", "PDF document", "Print"}, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which){ // this switch should determine which JS function I call
                        case 0: chosenMethod = 0; // here should be called JS function (eg. exportImage() from JS code)
                            Log.v("Dialog onClick()", "method chosen" + chosenMethod);
                            break;
                        case 1: chosenMethod = 1;
                            Log.v("Dialog onClick()", "method chosen" + chosenMethod);
                            break;
                        case 2: chosenMethod = 2;
                            Log.v("Dialog onClick()", "method chosen" + chosenMethod);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            })
            .create().show();
    Log.v("Dialog out of onClick", "method chosen" + chosenMethod);
    return chosenMethod;
}
```

Comment: do you want to know `how to call JS in WebView`?

Comment: @VladMatvienko yeah, gonna post some code

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:doSomething()");
```

any time after a webpage was loaded in your webview, to run a JS function.

If it doesn't work: check your webview settings (security / js).

Comment: Should I pass my `WebView` to the method or there is another option to call `loadUrl` on it?

Comment: You'd better open the dialog in your presenter/activity/fragment, and use a callback in the dialog, back to its creator. The callback implementation in the presenter/activity/fragment can do the JS call on the WebView. But this is actually another question. Good luck

Comment: It is working like a charm, but I got one problem when I call the function: `Uncaught ReferenceError: methodName is not defined `

Comment: Should **javascript** be instead name of the script from which I call method?